# Limiting the number of items in a tf.data.Dataset

Tags: testing, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

**tl;dr;** Can I limit the number of elements in a `tf.data.Dataset`?

A have a training and evaluation loop which processes the entire given `dataset`. This is not ideal for testing since it takes forever to go through the whole dataset. I can test this code by creating a Mock dataset or by limiting the number of elements of the `dataset` so the code only goes through, let's say, the first 10 datapoints. How can I do the second one?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to take only a fixed number of elements `n` from a `Dataset` is to use `Dataset.take(n)`. For example:

```
large_dataset = ...
small_dataset = large_dataset.take(10)
```